# android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException how to adapt this code that it runs in a seperate thread

Tags: java, android, multithreading, network-programming

I'm developing a software where a PC and a mobile talking to a server. When i run the code from the JAVA desktop app it gives me the following error
`android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException`

I tried to implement my class as a thread but i think i did not get it right. it still gives me the error

I would be glad about any support.

The class ServerAccessMobile is doing all the networking and has two public Methods, one for getting data from the server and one for setting data on the server

and this is how i want to execute it from any Activity / Service

```
ServerAccessMobile serverAccessMobile = new ServerAccessMobile();
ArrayList <String> dataFromServer = **serverAccessMobile.getDataFromServer()**;

ArrayList <String> dataToSend = .....

**serverAccessMobile.setDataOServer(dataToSend)**;
```

This is the code for the class ServerAccessMobile

```
public class ServerAccessMobile {

    // private variables
    private ObjectOutputStream outputStream; 
    private ObjectInputStream inputStream; 
    ...

    // constructor
    public ServerAccessMobile(String arg1)
    {
        ...
    } 

    **private ArrayList<String> run(ArrayList<String> messageToSendList)**
    {
        ArrayList <String> receivedMessageList = new ArrayList <String> ();

        try // connect to server, get streams, process connection
        {
            connectToServer(); // create a Socket to make connection

            getStreams(); // get the input and output streams

            sendData(messageToSendList);

            receivedMessageList = processConnection();
        }
        catch ( EOFException eofException )
        {
            System.out.println("\n terminated connection");
        } 
        catch ( IOException ioException )
        {
            ioException.printStackTrace();
        } 
        finally
        {
            closeConnection(); // close connection
        } 

        return receivedMessageList;
    } 

    public ArrayList <String > getDataFromServer(){

        ArrayList< String > commandMessage = new  ArrayList< String > ();
        commandMessage.add("GETDATA");

        ArrayList< String > receivedMessageList = new  ArrayList< String > ();

        // start server communication
        receivedMessageList = **run(commandMessage);**
    }

    public void setDataOnServer(ArrayList <String> messageToSendList){

        // start server communication
        **run(messageToSendList);**
    }
}
```

Now my question,

The code within the run() method should run in a seperate thread, not the ui thread
how do i implement it correct?

Thank u

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find detailed description about threads at the following link: http://developer.android.com/guide/components/processes-and-threads.html#Threads

You could do something like this

```
new Thread(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        ServerAccessMobile serverAccessMobile = new ServerAccessMobile(); 

    ArrayList <String> dataFromServer = **serverAccessMobile.getDataFromServer()**;

    ArrayList <String> dataToSend = .....

    serverAccessMobile.setDataOServer(dataToSend);
    }
}).start();
```

If you want to update the UI from this thread you'd have to call view.post(Runnable) method.